# Excel 2016 on MAC missing pictures after save

Tags: excel, image, vba, macos

I have an application created on Excel file with macros. It needs to be compatible with all Excel versions starting from 2007, both PC and MAC.

I have problem with pictures on MAC 2016. Whenever I save file, close it and reopen again I can't see pictures on the sheet which was active one during saving. Do anyone know what the problem is and how to deal with it?

My end users are not experienced enough and they get panicked if they can't see proper buttons...

My solution is to change active sheet using Workbook_BeforeSave event, but on MAC 2016 version I can't get back, because Workbook_AfterSave event doesn't work at all. As you can imagine it is not very convenient for end user to change active sheet when you just want to save your work.

I will be very grateful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether it helps, But you can give a try

Try using Workbook_BeforeClose event.

or else try to acheive the same using your code like switching to the sheet whatever you need

Sheets("activesheet").Select

Comment: unfortunately problem occurs during saving not closing the file.